# Duplicate Records showing SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, duplicates

I have a query that I am working with and I want to change the criteria of how a person is selected, instead of being selected by the type of doctor a person gets an order written by, I want to see results come back if a person has had activity performed by a physician of a certain type.

In some cases the same order will show up 1000 times or more.

Here is an example of some output from my query:

```
ROW_NUM | VISIT ID | ORD DESC | ORD NUM | ORD STS | ORD DTIME
1       | 123456   | INSERT F | 987654  | ACTIVE  | 2013-01-01 10:01:00.000
2       | 123456   | INSERT F | 987654  | ACTIVE  | 2013-01-01 10:01:00.000
3       | 123456   | INSERT F | 987654  | ACTIVE  | 2013-01-01 10:01:00.000
.
.
.
568     | 123456   | INSERT F | 987654  | ACTIVE  | 2013-01-01 10:01:00.000
```

As shown the order number is the same, so I only need the one instance of the order where it is Active, In Progress, Complete, etc. This query is very similar to another one, the only difference is the in how I am asking the question. I feel this newer version would be more accurate provided I get it working.  Here is the query providing the results above:

```
DECLARE @SD DATETIME
DECLARE @ED DATETIME
SET @SD = '2013-06-01';
SET @ED = '2013-06-30';

WITH [SX FLAG] AS (
    SELECT 
    PV.PtNo_Num AS [VISIT ID]
    , PV.Med_Rec_No AS MRN
    , PV.vst_start_dtime AS ADM
    , PV.vst_end_dtime AS DISCH
    , PV.Days_Stay AS LOS
    , PV.pt_type AS [PT TYPE]
    , PV.hosp_svc AS [HOSP SVC]
    , SO.ord_no AS [ORD NUM]
    , X.[ORD DESC]
    , SO.pty_name AS [PARTY NAME]
    , OSM.ord_sts AS [ORD STS]
    , SOS.prcs_dtime AS [ORD STS TIME]
    , DATEDIFF(DAY,PV.vst_start_dtime,SOS.prcs_dtime) AS [ADM TO ORD STS IN DAYS]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN [ORD DESC] IN ('INSERT FOLEY', 'REMOVE FOLEY') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        OVER (PARTITION BY PV.PTNO_NUM) AS HasInsertRemoveFoley
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ACDV.actv_group = 'OR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        OVER (PARTITION BY PV.PTNO_NUM) AS HasORTime

    FROM smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V PV
    JOIN smsmir.sr_ord SO
    ON PV.PtNo_Num = SO.episode_no
    JOIN smsmir.sr_ord_sts_hist SOS
    ON SO.ord_no = SOS.ord_no
    JOIN smsmir.ord_sts_modf_mstr OSM
    ON SOS.hist_sts = OSM.ord_sts_modf_cd
    JOIN smsdss.actv_fct_v AFV
    ON PV.Pt_No = AFV.pt_id
    JOIN smsdss.actv_cd_dim_v ACDV
    ON AFV.actv_cd = ACDV.actv_cd

    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN SO.svc_desc = 'INSERT FOLEY CATHETER' THEN 'INSERT FOLEY'
                WHEN SO.svc_desc = 'INSERT INDWELLING URINARY CATHETER TO GRAVITY DRAINAGE' THEN 'INSERT FOLEY'
                WHEN SO.svc_desc = 'REMOVE INDWELLING URINARY CATHETER' THEN 'REMOVE FOLEY'
                ELSE SO.svc_desc
            END AS [ORD DESC]
            ) X


    WHERE PV.Adm_Date BETWEEN @SD AND @ED
    AND SO.svc_cd IN ('PCO_REMFOLEY' -- <-- The orders I am looking for
        ,'PCO_INSRTFOLEY'       -- <-- for patients who have had a
        ,'PCO_INSTFOLEY'        -- <-- surgical procedure
        ,'PCO_URIMETER'
        )
     -- I don't want patients who fall into these pt types
    AND PV.hosp_svc NOT IN (
        'DIA'
        ,'DMS'
        ,'EME'
        )
     -- This is supposed to kick out orders that were 'Discontinued'
     -- or orders that were 'Canceled'
    AND SO.ord_no NOT IN (
        SELECT SO.ord_no

        FROM smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V PV
        JOIN smsmir.sr_ord SO
        ON PV.PtNo_Num = SO.episode_no
        JOIN smsmir.sr_ord_sts_hist SOS
        ON SO.ord_no = SOS.ord_no
        JOIN smsmir.ord_sts_modf_mstr OSM
        ON SOS.hist_sts = OSM.ord_sts_modf_cd
        JOIN smsdss.actv_fct_v AFV -- <-- gets pt activity
        ON PV.Pt_No = AFV.pt_id
        JOIN smsdss.actv_cd_dim_v ACDV -- <-- tells me if pt had OR Time
        ON AFV.actv_cd = ACDV.actv_cd

        WHERE OSM.ord_sts = 'DISCONTINUE' -- <-- don't want these orders
        AND SO.svc_cd IN ('PCO_REMFOLEY'  -- <-- to show if they were
        ,'PCO_INSRTFOLEY'                 -- <-- canned / discontinued
        ,'PCO_INSTFOLEY'
        ,'PCO_URIMETER'
        )
    )
)
SELECT *
FROM [SX FLAG]
WHERE HasInsertRemoveFoley = 1
AND HasORTime = 1
```

Thank you,

Comment: Downvoter can you tell me why so I can make an improvement? Downvoting without explanation does no one any good, ie, am I unclear, is it poorly written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be up to you to determine whether your query produces correct or incorrect results.  We can't do that for you.

If the only problem with the results is that the same row occurs multiple times in the result table, there's an easy way to check for that:  Use "SELECT DISTINCT" instead of "SELECT".  This could slow your query down a lot, but it might help you debug it.

Comment: No wonder I got downvoted, someone stamp fail on my forhead. I obviously know only I can tell if the result set is right but -1 to me for not using `DISTINCT`